# update order from Unfulfilled to Fulfilled with Shopify API

Tags: php, api, shopify

Does anyone know how to update an order's Fulfillment status from Unfulfilled to Fulfilled with Shopify's API? I am using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using the fulfillment APi